# Is there a way to see & keep track of registers in dnSpy?

Tags: disassembly, debugging, .net, c#

Hello I am trying to see if there is a way to see & keep track of the IP, and other registers as you would in OllyDbg or x64Dbg?

Answer (score 1):

Well, not really.

`dnSpy` is not a native debugger like `OllyDbg`/`x64Dbg` but rather a managed one. It is used for .NET assemblies which also are not native applications. The code is IL and it is stack-based so there are no registers on that level. Also there's not really a way to track instruction pointer.